# Изменение вида ячейки DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, .net

Вытягиваю данные в `DataGrid` получается так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно, 2й и 3й столбцы типа `DataTime`. Вопрос: как вместо такого (текстового) отображения поставить `datePicker` (т е получается нужно определить отображения для столбца определенного типа, т к есть несколько перегрузок данного класса, и кол-во столбцов может меняться как и их тип.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если надо что то нестандартное, то вы можете использовать `DataGridTemplateColumn`.
Давайте попробуем сделать то, что вы хотите:

1. Создаем `DataGrid`, привязываем его и убираем автоматическую генерацию столбцов:

   ```
   <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding TestData}" AutoGenerateColumns="False"/>
   ```
2. Добавим колонку к примеру с именем элемента. Для этого мы внутри элемента обозначаем `DataGrid.Columns` c `DataGridTextColumn` элементом:

   ```
   <DataGrid.Columns>
       <DataGridTextColumn Header="Имя" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
   </DataGrid.Columns>
   ```
3. Теперь создадим столбец с датой. Задача у нас, это добавить туда элемент DatePicker. Элемент не стандартный, значит берем `DataGridTemplateColumn`. У него есть два интересных для нас свойства `CellTemplate` и `CellEditingTemplate`. Первый отвечает за вид самой ячейки, а второй за вид ячейки при изменении. По сути это обычные шаблоны в которых мы можем реализовать `DataTemplate` со своим элементом. Для примера сделаем что бы обычный вид был в виде текста, а при изменении использовался `DatePicker`:

   ```
   <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Дата" >
       <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding Date, StringFormat=d}" />
           </DataTemplate>
       </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
       <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
               <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Date}" />
           </DataTemplate>
       </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
   </DataGridTemplateColumn>
   ```

Теперь запускаем и смотрим результат:

[image: Result]

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь!

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц Рад помочь. Удачи в изучении WPF!