# Как добавить DataGrid в ячейку?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

На макете имеется DataGrid, у которого один столбец и одна ячейка. Как добавить ещё один (вложенный выходит) DataGrid в эту ячейку? Что-то такое:

[image: пример желаемой раскладки]

Интересует способ xaml преимущественно (или дизайнер).

Comment: шаблон ячейки прописать?

Comment: @tym32167 не подскажете самый простой пример?

Comment: [раз](https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/ru/89/%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-datagrid/%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B1%D1%86%D1%8B-datagrid/), [два](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/895475/%D0%98%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D1%8F%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B8-datagrid)

Comment: @tym32167 премного благодарен!

Comment: @tum32167 извините, я полностью разобрался, но никак не могу понять одну вещь : как установить данные в эту вложенную таблицу? С любым элементом получилось, но только не с таблицей. Биндил колонки вложенной таблицы, но не помогло. И имя этой таблицы, если задать, не виднО.

Comment: [три](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/94ac4531-0dde-45f4-a266-f8197d9c42d8/show-db-data-in-nested-datagrid-in-wpf-?forum=wpf)

Comment: @tym32167 всё отлично, спасибо! Если хотите - оформите ответ, я приму его, как верный.

Comment: Лучше вы оформите как у вас получилось, будет закрывашка для будущих подобных вопросов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итак, проблема решена. XAML разметка(таблица, один столбец, в ячейке вложенная таблица, в ней три столбца и некоторое количество строк):

```
 <DataGrid Name="table1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Поток номер 1" >
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding DataThreadsAll}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False">  
                                <DataGrid.Columns>
                                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Ri" Binding="{Binding Ri}" />
                                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Zi" Binding="{Binding Zi}" />
                                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Tk" Binding="{Binding Tk}" />
                                </DataGrid.Columns>
                            </DataGrid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

И заполнение через код C#:

```
public class DataTable
{
    public List<DataThreads> DataThreadsAll { get; set; }
}

public class DataThreads
{
    public double Ri { get; set; }
    public double Zi { get; set; }
    public double Tk { get; set; }
}
```

И где-то создать коллекцию и присвоить её:

```
DataTable dt = new 
{
DataThreadsAll = new List<DataThreads>()
{
    new DataThreads() { Ri = 0, Zi = 0, Tk = 0},
    new DataThreads() { Ri = 1, Zi = 1, Tk = 1},
    new DataThreads() { Ri = 2, Zi = 2, Tk = 2}
 }
 };
 List<DataTable> dtList = new List<DataTable>() { dt };
 table1.ItemsSource = dtList;
```

Два класса - это и есть данные, причем свойство *DataThreadsAll* - это данные для вложенной таблицы. А для того, чтобы данные попали во вложенную таблицу, у нее надо установить свойство *ItemsSource*.